# Why do we use objects in OOP

Tags: oop

I'm new to programming and especially OOP. I have been learning OOP in JS for some time and encountered the term object in OOP.

Is it true that if we do not use objects then we have to repeat (by copy and pasting) the same logic over and over then if we find a bug in the logic then we have to change in each place where that logic is used.

Thanks to the use of object we encapsulate a certain logic in one place and then reuse it and even if later we find a bug in the logic then there is only one place where we need to make changes to which is object only.

So, basically, object is responsible for only one logic which we can reuse instead of copy and pasting the logic in several places. Is my understanding of objects true guys?

Comment: This question is far too broad for SO's Q&A format, I suggest reading OOP introductory books/tutorials. *"Is it true that if we do not use objects then we have to repeat(by copying and pasting) the same logic over and over..."* No, it isn't. Functions can do that.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a Javascript example if the post is tagged as such.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Wikipedia's definition of *object*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science)). None of the things you named are exclusively related to objects.

Comment: @Bergi, thank you for your kind comments, frankly, I read truckload of articles on OOP but the concept of objects do not want to get in my head. At the moment, I understood objects as a wrapper of certain logic which we can reuse then. Is that true? if not, please can you explain in simple way

Comment: @Dickens An object foremost is a wrapper of data. Then, in comparison to a plain record/struct, it also has associated methods with code.

Comment: @Bergi, ok, for example whenever you create some project how do you subconsciously know that here I need to use object just what situation makes you create an object. How I subconsciously get object is that whenever a certain logic is used in several places I get that no I need to create an object and reuse it to achieve dry.

Comment: @Dickens One creates an object when one has data values that belong together. (And if one decided to use object-orientation, which is the norm though, at least in js). No, one does not (or rarely) introduce objects to avoid code repetition. Normally, when there is code that you want to DRY up, you already have the objects in place on which the new method should be placed.

Comment: @Bergi, if I get you correctly, with objects we just connect all related data and methods inside one unit. Right? Is it true that with objects we break our app into pieces like into lego blocks. So, basically the fact that objects help us break our app into units are why objects are so beneficial. Is that true?

Comment: @Dickens Yes, precisely. In OOP, objects are the primary [modular building blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) to [compose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) our applications from, and if done right it's beneficial [for all kinds of reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)). (That said, objects are used for all kinds of purposes in OOP, since everything is an object - which makes the distinction a bit unclear sometimes)

Comment: @Dickens you need to use objects for basically anything. So, the choice is often clear. The objects will be the *representations* of whatever real world thing you're working with. So, for example, if you have some online site you'd have objects along the line of `Item` that is sold and `Category` that holds related goods. You'd also have stuff like `PaymentInformation` to represent buying an item and `User` who buys or sells the item. These would likely be the main ones but you'd also have others that manage these, e.g., `ItemSorter` to order lists of items.

Comment: @VLAZ, ok then why array is an object and function is an object. Just can you please clarify on "real world thing you're working with". Just when you create a project what makes you choose to create an object subconsciously.

Comment: @Dickens don't mix JS stuff with OOP. A lot of the JS design is not object oriented. Or *is* but in a very different way than traditional OO. An array is an object because that's how JS implemented it. Similarly for a function. Both are special objects in their own way - a function is a *callable* object (what makes it a function), while an array inherits from the Array prototype and will behave slightly differently than a plain object which has numerically indexed keys. To be clear, that's not usually how OO programs behave.

Comment: @Dickens as for how you define the objects in your program - I already gave you an example. You'd have to define the *actors* in your situation - for a shop, that's items, collections of items, buyers, sellers, etc. and then you'd create an object to represent each. You'd later fill in with other objects that do more stuff you need - as I mentioned, you can have an `ItemSorter` whose job is to sort items. You can also have other stuff like a `Cart` which people put their future purchases in. And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK first of all "copy/past" (code duplication) is always a bad idea. But even without objects you can write code in functions and use them to keep your code clean!

In OOP you try to treat everything as an object that has properties and maybe some functions. This helps you not only to keep your code clean but is makes working with data easier and enables you to think bigger and gives you the chance to add another layer of abstraction!

So OOP and software design patterns help keeping code clean and simple so that you can achieve bigger things. Just imagine writing a complex software but not keeping everything clean in objects but rather in functions that only take and return primitive data or maybe arrays. It would be much harder to wrap your head around this, or find bugs!

Comment: "*but rather in functions that only take and return primitive data or maybe arrays*" functional programming does that. Well, it rarely does only use primitive types but it usually has tools of easily defining your own types based on previous ones. For example unions or sum types. You also often get wrappers that can encapsulate primitive types for better expressiveness, like a Maybe or Either that can wrap a plain string based on how you want to handle the case where the string is missing. FP tends to have success, even if less mainstream than OOP, so I would say that it works.

Comment: @Vl4dimyr, thank you very much for your kind explanation, let me explain briefly how I get objects in OOP, with objects we encapsulate a certain logic, for example, logic that counts how old you are if we give a certain argument. If I am mistaken, you cannot imagine how grateful I would be if you told me how you subcounsciously  understand aha here I need to create an object. Yes I have read books on OOP but the concept of OOP does not want to get in my head

Comment: @VLAZ Yes you are right! To me it just seams like all the complex software works better with OOP because you can easily categorize things into objects or inherit from another object. The same way it's easier to take a complex task and chop it into little parts that can be understood and solved and then put together. I don't say functional programming wouldn't work! But FP maybe better for other things than OOP!

Comment: "*you can easily categorize things into objects or inherit from another object*" this is not really an argument *for* OOP, since it's (most of the times) a bad OOP design. Remember - composition over inheritance. Do not share logic through inheritance as that leads to [the Yo-yo problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_problem). You can break tasks into small units and make those units be objects, thus leading to OOP but each should (ideally) be self-contained.

Comment: @Vl4dimyr, ok, can I think of objects kinda like HOC in React, yes yes I know HOC is something different than object. But we create HOC whenever we want to escape logic duplication is object the same in OOP. My last question is that you wrote that "object makes working with data easier and enables you to think bigger and gives you the chance to add another layer of abstraction". Please can you give example and clarify a bit

Comment: @Dickens if you read books you most likely came across examples that tried to show you how this works. But is simple in OOP everything is an object and you need to find out what the thing that you want to add or implement is and to which object you should add it or if you have to create a new one. So let's say you would make a software that manages client data, and you want to add the birthdate then it is an attribute of the client object. And if you want to add the Address it is also an attribute of the client object, but it also contains attributes that don't belong inside the client object

Comment: e.g. street or postcode these are part of an address but don't depend on the client, the clients address itself belongs to the client but the attribute street belongs to an address that's why it should be put in an address object and later if you would add companies you could use the address again...

Comment: @VLAZ bad design is a problem in all languages and rather caused by developers than the programming paradigm. And all paradigms have their flaws after all they are made by humans! And I don't try to defend OOP over FP I use OOP because that's what I learned and what I like and also I'm making money with it =P but in the end the task/problem needs to be analysed and a programming paradigm needs to be chosen and the decision is often based on what the developer knows or the boss/customer wants...

Comment: @Dickens in react you are using objects/classes: `class XYZ extends Component` you inherit all that `Component` can do and you start overwriting functions... but also it allows React to use your component (when you render it via React) because it's an instance of `Component`

Comment: @Vl4dimyr, ok,  with objects we just connect all related data and methods inside one unit. Right? Is it true that with objects we break our app into pieces like into lego blocks. So, basically the fact that objects help us break our app into units are why objects are so beneficial. Is that true? P.S sorry for so many questions

Comment: @Dickens I think Lego blocks are a good analogy but maybe compare it to real world things you would call a phone, a phone even though its made of a speaker, a microphone, a display and more but those components are objects themselves and contain other objects like wires, the world is full of objects ...

Comment: @Vl4dimyr, ok, your example with phone is quite clear, ok objects are like components in React but I wonder is there any guidelines on how to divide system into object components. For example, it is clear and easy to divide UI into components but how about back-end service. What should be considered an object in, say, microservices.

Comment: @Dickens ok for something like a microservice think what are the tasks that need to be done, that roughly determines your microservices, inside those services you would try to find out what attributes you have and need to work with, and then you will see if they depend on each other or belong together, find out if you can put them in an object and give it a name that fits or e.g. if you would put `subscriptionStatus` and `birthdate` in the same object it's difficult to name it because `subscriptionStatus` would be part of a subscription object and `birthdate` of a user ...

Comment: I guess this is something you will learn over time just by gathering experience and reading more books but also code!